# best partitioning mechanism based on clients

Tags: plsql, oracle12c

we have a multi client database and was willing to partition big tables of our database based on the client_id, since the client can be deleted/added on a day to day basis. which partition would be the best approach

Comment: If you have known and short list of clients use `list` partition else go for `range` partition.

Comment: range would merge the data of clients right? List is fine but when every client is added the alter of partition is required right? or is there an option to automatically create a partition when a new client ID comes in for list partition?

Comment: I finally found an answer with Oracle 12c:- 
 alter table your_table modify partition by list (client_id) automatic (partition p_0 values (0));